# Stalling state sync, dropping peer peer=a773b13bcef51ac8

Tags: ether

I'm trying to syncronize with blockchain my ethereum wallet. And getting each attempt this

> error:Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=a773b13bcef51ac8

Can any one suggest a cure to it? I did delete the chaindata folder few times. it did not help.

The log is below:

```
INFO [12-10|10:26:30] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/windows-amd64/go1.9
INFO [12-10|10:26:30] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Ethereum\\geth\\chaindata cache=1024 handles=1024
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Ethereum\\geth\\ethash count=3
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Ethash                          count=2
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Loaded most recent local header          number=4703629 hash=b85d64…6cb02d td=1688528255391708891116
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0       hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=4703409 hash=b97d77…0075ec td=1688193374350101343274
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Upgrading chain index                    type=bloombits percentage=99
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [12-10|10:26:44] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [12-10|10:26:45] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [12-10|10:26:45] Mapped network port                      proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface=NAT-PMP(192.168.1.1)
INFO [12-10|10:26:46] UDP listener up                          self=enode://502b2ad3dd7968f7f8f15e9712066291e058106ce08fcd6e89ffc4f2f7a66538398acf270c3ac78579a3831629826fadf3fea8ab4d3aa13b5809c4919a17e0ad@178.124.154.132:30303
INFO [12-10|10:26:46] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://502b2ad3dd7968f7f8f15e9712066291e058106ce08fcd6e89ffc4f2f7a66538398acf270c3ac78579a3831629826fadf3fea8ab4d3aa13b5809c4919a17e0ad@178.124.154.132:30303
INFO [12-10|10:26:46] Mapped network port                      proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface=NAT-PMP(192.168.1.1)
INFO [12-10|10:26:46] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc 
INFO [12-10|10:26:49] Finished upgrading chain index           type=bloombits
INFO [12-10|10:26:51] Block synchronisation started 
INFO [12-10|10:27:53] Imported new block headers               count=548 elapsed=667.038ms number=4704177 hash=afbaf8…d24a6e ignored=220
INFO [12-10|10:27:55] Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=1.216s    number=4706225 hash=5b1bdc…9d26cb ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:27:56] Imported new block headers               count=640  elapsed=661.037ms number=4706865 hash=180132…f627e8 ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:27:57] Imported new block headers               count=159  elapsed=1.324s    number=4707024 hash=96b35f…39368d ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:27:58] Imported new block receipts              count=4    elapsed=19.001ms  bytes=395143 number=4703413 hash=449924…06d3ce ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:28:05] Imported new block receipts              count=2    elapsed=13.000ms  bytes=253178 number=4703415 hash=ec7326…0049a7 ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:28:29] Imported new block receipts              count=10   elapsed=55.003ms  bytes=1039285 number=4703425 hash=de107b…dcce05 ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:28:57] Imported new block receipts              count=843  elapsed=5.729s    bytes=71781312 number=4704268 hash=29513c…fa1c80 ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:29:01] Imported new block receipts              count=501  elapsed=3.281s    bytes=39795631 number=4704769 hash=9611a6…b403f7 ignored=0
WARN [12-10|10:29:05] Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=8e9d682dc2ab5c9f
INFO [12-10|10:29:05] Imported new block receipts              count=490  elapsed=3.513s    bytes=36716743 number=4705259 hash=de72a2…5ef5ec ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:29:18] Imported new block receipts              count=17   elapsed=289.016ms bytes=1240366  number=4705276 hash=8f9838…f139cf ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:29:33] Imported new block receipts              count=747  elapsed=12.067s   bytes=58914022 number=4706023 hash=4d596d…6f89fc ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:29:49] Imported new block receipts              count=590  elapsed=15.967s   bytes=56553252 number=4706613 hash=8c2cd1…84a576 ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:29:57] Imported new block receipts              count=295  elapsed=7.709s    bytes=24220190 number=4706908 hash=20386f…6dc30a ignored=0
INFO [12-10|10:37:25] Imported new state entries               count=273  elapsed=22.001ms  processed=273 pending=4369 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:40:10] Imported new state entries               count=527  elapsed=0s        processed=800 pending=12789 retry=89 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:40:35] Imported new state entries               count=212  elapsed=0s        processed=1012 pending=15575 retry=2  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:41:33] Imported new state entries               count=425  elapsed=0s        processed=1437 pending=20473 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:43:11] Imported new state entries               count=535  elapsed=0s        processed=1972 pending=22345 retry=2  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:43:20] Imported new state entries               count=1021 elapsed=176.010ms processed=2993 pending=22077 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:43:25] Imported new state entries               count=976  elapsed=66.003ms  processed=3969 pending=21432 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:43:37] Imported new state entries               count=937  elapsed=61.003ms  processed=4906 pending=21347 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:44:14] Imported new state entries               count=764  elapsed=4.000ms   processed=5670 pending=21390 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
WARN [12-10|10:44:14] Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=b9a84accba79a733
INFO [12-10|10:44:21] Imported new state entries               count=1177 elapsed=33.001ms  processed=6847 pending=20603 retry=34 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:45:43] Imported new state entries               count=720  elapsed=4.000ms   processed=7567 pending=21446 retry=29 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:45:55] Imported new state entries               count=992  elapsed=6.000ms   processed=8559 pending=21112 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:46:13] Imported new state entries               count=971  elapsed=5.000ms   processed=9530 pending=21122 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:46:44] Imported new state entries               count=1033 elapsed=36.002ms  processed=10563 pending=20647 retry=2  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:47:01] Imported new state entries               count=1148 elapsed=43.002ms  processed=11711 pending=20250 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:47:37] Imported new state entries               count=647  elapsed=183.010ms processed=12358 pending=20322 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:47:47] Imported new state entries               count=1107 elapsed=8.000ms   processed=13465 pending=19766 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:48:44] Imported new state entries               count=739  elapsed=4.000ms   processed=14204 pending=20052 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:48:56] Imported new state entries               count=1147 elapsed=7.000ms   processed=15351 pending=20158 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:49:10] Imported new state entries               count=1376 elapsed=9.000ms   processed=16727 pending=19497 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:50:27] Imported new state entries               count=742  elapsed=4.000ms   processed=17469 pending=19634 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:50:43] Imported new state entries               count=961  elapsed=7.000ms   processed=18430 pending=19242 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:50:59] Imported new state entries               count=859  elapsed=6.000ms   processed=19289 pending=19360 retry=2  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:51:15] Imported new state entries               count=765  elapsed=5.000ms   processed=20054 pending=19203 retry=1  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:51:24] Imported new state entries               count=969  elapsed=42.002ms  processed=21023 pending=18755 retry=0  duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:51:46] Imported new state entries               count=653  elapsed=32.001ms  processed=21676 pending=19501 retry=374 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [12-10|10:51:58] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=3.398s    processed=21676 pending=19806 retry=297 duplicate=15 unexpected=10
WARN [12-10|10:51:59] Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=a773b13bcef51ac8
INFO [12-10|10:52:10] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=11.573s   processed=21676 pending=20441 retry=151 duplicate=42 unexpected=34
INFO [12-10|10:52:10] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=0s        processed=21676 pending=20441 retry=134 duplicate=42 unexpected=35
INFO [12-10|10:52:11] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=0s        processed=21676 pending=20606 retry=134 duplicate=79 unexpected=69
INFO [12-10|10:52:11] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=1.000ms   processed=21676 pending=20606 retry=67  duplicate=102 unexpected=90
INFO [12-10|10:52:11] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=43.002ms  processed=21676 pending=20609 retry=25  duplicate=135 unexpected=128
INFO [12-10|10:52:11] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=0s        processed=21676 pending=20609 retry=8   duplicate=136 unexpected=128
INFO [12-10|10:52:11] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=0s        processed=21676 pending=20609 retry=1   duplicate=137 unexpected=128
INFO [12-10|10:52:11] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=0s        processed=21676 pending=20609 retry=7   duplicate=139 unexpected=130
INFO [12-10|10:52:12] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=0s        processed=21676 pending=20608 retry=9   duplicate=162 unexpected=149
INFO [12-10|10:52:12] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=1ms       processed=21676 pending=20604 retry=8   duplicate=163 unexpected=149
INFO [12-10|10:52:12] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=75.004ms  processed=21676 pending=20578 retry=0   duplicate=176 unexpected=160
INFO [12-10|10:52:12] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=23.001ms  processed=21676 pending=20537 retry=2   duplicate=180 unexpected=164
INFO [12-10|10:52:12] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=0s        processed=21676 pending=20535 retry=2   duplicate=224 unexpected=187
INFO [12-10|10:52:12] Imported new state entries               count=756  elapsed=4.000ms   processed=22432 pending=20457 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=187
INFO [12-10|10:52:26] Imported new state entries               count=1415 elapsed=9.000ms   processed=23847 pending=19923 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=187
INFO [12-10|10:52:31] Imported new state entries               count=1308 elapsed=14.000ms  processed=25155 pending=19098 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=187
INFO [12-10|10:52:40] Imported new state entries               count=1017 elapsed=30.001ms  processed=26172 pending=18666 retry=20  duplicate=224 unexpected=187
INFO [12-10|10:52:50] Imported new state entries               count=1026 elapsed=5.000ms   processed=27198 pending=19451 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=187
INFO [12-10|10:52:53] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=38.002ms  processed=27198 pending=19014 retry=4   duplicate=224 unexpected=188
INFO [12-10|10:53:28] Imported new state entries               count=1633 elapsed=40.002ms  processed=28831 pending=18570 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=188
INFO [12-10|10:54:55] Imported new state entries               count=487  elapsed=2.000ms   processed=29318 pending=19487 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=188
INFO [12-10|10:55:07] Imported new state entries               count=1093 elapsed=6.000ms   processed=30411 pending=19259 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=188
INFO [12-10|10:55:16] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=6.139s    processed=30411 pending=18531 retry=2   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:55:17] Imported new state entries               count=1043 elapsed=137.007ms processed=31454 pending=18531 retry=2   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:55:25] Imported new state entries               count=1173 elapsed=12.000ms  processed=32627 pending=17754 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:56:31] Imported new state entries               count=701  elapsed=5.000ms   processed=33328 pending=18386 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:56:42] Imported new state entries               count=1010 elapsed=8.000ms   processed=34338 pending=17742 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:56:55] Imported new state entries               count=1004 elapsed=8.000ms   processed=35342 pending=17423 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
WARN [12-10|10:57:10] Stalling state sync, dropping peer       peer=586db8d392e24f9c
INFO [12-10|10:57:33] Imported new state entries               count=630  elapsed=4.000ms   processed=35972 pending=17952 retry=2   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:57:41] Imported new state entries               count=1089 elapsed=8.000ms   processed=37061 pending=17385 retry=1   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:58:15] Imported new state entries               count=1032 elapsed=8.000ms   processed=38093 pending=17310 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:58:50] Imported new state entries               count=894  elapsed=6.000ms   processed=38987 pending=17397 retry=0   duplicate=224 unexpected=194
INFO [12-10|10:58:55]
```